# OWASP ZAP JVM contention with same Selenium Grid ports

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, owasp, zap

I am attempting to run Selenium automation scripts through the selenium grid server with ZAP sitting on the same port analyzing the thru traffic. However, I am having a point of contention with both (selenium grid & ZAP) JVM's sitting on the same port (JVM port already in use error). Is there a way around this? Or a better way of using ZAP with Selenium Grid?

Comment: Please add more information to what is the issue. What do you mean JVM contention ? How are you starting both the servers ? Please add the exact command that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you cant have 2 processes listening on the same port.

Try configuring your Selenium Grid to proxy through ZAP. Hopefully it will have a specific option to do that, if not then you can try using the standard JVM flags http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort.